# Android OSのイメージファイルのビルドについて

Tags: android, makefile

Android Open Source Project(AOSP)からイメージファイル(.img or .iso)を作成したいのですが、どのようにすればいいのかわかりません。
Android-x86プロジェクトであれば下記のようにして.isoファイルを作成できるようなのですが

```
make iso_img TARGET_PRODUCT=&target_name
```

AOSPではiso_imgというオプションを付けると

```
FAILED: ninja: unknown target 'img_iso', did you mean 'imgdiff'?
19:29:46 ninja failed with: exit status 1
make: *** [run_soong_ui] Error 1
```

と出てしまいます。
何か知っていらっしゃる方、お教えいただけると幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: この記事 [AOSP環境構築 備忘録](https://qiita.com/natmark/items/09802c7f16733cd77f8e) が参考になるのでは？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
各imgデータが生成されるところまでは行ったのですが、これを一般的なx86機(またはVM)で起動するために一つのisoファイルを生成する方法がわからなくて困ってしました。

Comment: 方向性が違うかもしれませんが、こんな記事があり、VirtualBoxやQEMUで動かせるイメージが作れるようです。[How can I automate the installation of a custom Android-x86 ISO for testing purposes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45894556/9014308)、[kylemanna/docker-aosp](https://github.com/kylemanna/docker-aosp)